# Pull out data from cells and columns which are different based on flag

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an ESTIMATE sheet which has several headings as Heading1, Heading2 and so on (see image). There is total under each heading indicated by flag “tot”. I wish to pull out the headings from the sheet and indicate the corresponding total under the heading on a different sheet named ABSTRACT sheet. 
I tried INDEX MATCH formula to pull out the value corresponding to flag “tot”, but it is returning only the first instance. 
The snapshot of ESTIMATE sheet and ABSTRACT sheet is as shown.
Could anyone help?

ESTIMATE SHEET

[image]

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=63829334703767014830

ABSTRACT SHEET

[image]

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=68637823078246367804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list, put this in C4 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(ESTIMATE!D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(ESTIMATE!$C$2:INDEX(ESTIMATE!C:C,MATCH("zzz",ESTIMATE!C:C)))/(ESTIMATE!$C$2:INDEX(ESTIMATE!C:C,MATCH("zzz",ESTIMATE!C:C))="h"),ROW(1:1)))
```

Then to get the total, use this in D4 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(ESTIMATE!H:H,MATCH("tot",INDEX(ESTIMATE!B:B,MATCH(C4,ESTIMATE!D:D,0)):ESTIMATE!B$1040000,0)+MATCH(C4,ESTIMATE!D:D,0)-1)
```

It finds the first instance of `tot` after finding the correct Heading.  Then returns the value from column H of that row.

[image]

Comment: The code returned error as the search column was indicated as `C:C` instead of `B:B`. I corrected this and used the following
`=INDEX(ESTIMATE!H:H,MATCH("tot",INDEX(ESTIMATE!B:B,MATCH(C4,ESTIMATE!D:D,0)):ESTIMATE!B$1040000,0)+MATCH(C4,ESTIMATE!D:D,0)-` 
It works as desired - @Scott

Comment: @MelvinKoshy I edited and changed the column to B.  It works for me.  Try the new formula.

Comment: @MelvinKoshy just to make sure, this will only work in Excel.  It will not work in GoogleSheets.

Comment: In the original question, I intended that the text Heading1, Heading2 … should appear automatically in ABSTRACT sheet from cell **C4** downwards, without typing. 
Though, the given solution would suffice my requirement, I am interested to know if it can be done?